# How to change AdMob Currency

Tags: android, admob, adsense

How can I change my Google AdMob Currency?

My account is currently in GBP and I want to change it in USD. I had no Google AdSense account before. I was only using Google AdMob, Google Ads and Google Play. I've closed the Google Ads Account and made a new one in USD, I've linked it with my Google Play account, but I can't link any of them with Admob.

In the AdMob Settings, I have the Google AdMob and AdSense customer IDs that are still the old ones (the accounts that are now cancelled). How can I change those IDs?

I think I need to cancel my AdMob account and open a new one with the new Google AdSense/Ads accounts. Is this the only way to do it?